# Cannot find symbol - constructor (java)

Tags: java, constructor

```
public class Picture
{

    private Square s1;
    private Square s2;
    private Square s3;
    private Square s4;
    private Square s5;
    private Square s6;
    private Square s7;
    private Square s8;
    private Square s9;


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Picture
     */
    public Picture()
    {
        // nothing to do... instance variables are automatically set to null
    }

    /**
     * Draw this picture.
     */
    public void draw()
    {
      s1 = new Square(23,87,104,"red",true);
      s2 = new Square(23,112,104,"yellow",true);
      s3 = new Square(23,137,104,"magenta",true);
      s4 = new Square(23,87,129,"blue",true);
      s5 = new Square(23,112,129,"green",true);
      s6 = new Square(23,137,129,"yellow",true);
      s7 = new Square(23,87,154,"magenta",true);
      s8 = new Square(23,112,154,"red",true);
      s9 = new Square(23,137,154,"blue",true);
    }

}
```

I am having to create a rubix cube for class and cannot seem to get this to work. I keep getting the error:

```
cannot find symbol - constructor Square(int,int,int,java.lang.String,boolean)
```

Does anyone see where I am going wrong? Please help

Answer (score 3):

You have not included the source for `Square`, but I can tell you that it doesn't have a public constructor that has those parameters. These lines are causing the problem:

```
s1 = new Square(23,87,104,"red",true); // etc
```

Your `Square` class would need to have a constructor like this:

```
public class Square {
    public Square(int a, int b, int c, String color, boolean flag) {
    }
}
```